# Connection error, socket io on the client side

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I ran into such a problem, my client does not connect to a remote server, I start wiretapping through node js (picture below) and try to connect to the server (I covered up the link to the site so as not to burn it).

**Сlient side code**

```js
const host_counter = "http://example-site.com:3000";
// PASS your query parameters
const randomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
const queryParams = { userId: randomId };
const socket = io(host_counter, {
    path: "/pathToConnection",
    transports: ['websocket'],  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/52180905/8987128
    upgrade: false,
    query: queryParams,
    reconnection: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    allowEIO3: true
});
```

**Сode from node js**

```js
const _ = require("lodash");
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const server = app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`We are Listening on port ${port}...`);
});

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    path: "/pathToConnection"
});
let users = {};
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log('client connection');
    let userId = socket.handshake.query.userId; // GET USER ID

    // CHECK IS USER EXHIST 
    if (!users[userId]) users[userId] = [];
  
    // PUSH SOCKET ID FOR PARTICULAR USER ID
    users[userId].push(socket.id);
     
    // USER IS ONLINE BROAD CAST TO ALL CONNECTED USERS
    io.sockets.emit("online", userId);
    console.log(userId, "Is Online!", socket.id);
  
    // DISCONNECT EVENT
    socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
  
      // REMOVE FROM SOCKET USERS
      _.remove(users[userId], (u) => u === socket.id);
      if (users[userId].length === 0) {
        // ISER IS OFFLINE BROAD CAST TO ALL CONNECTED USERS
        io.sockets.emit("offline", userId);
        // REMOVE OBJECT
        delete users[userId];
      }
     
      socket.disconnect(); // DISCONNECT SOCKET
  
      console.log(userId, "Is Offline!", socket.id);
  
    });
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the server you're connecting to a webSocket server or a socket.io server?  Is it also configured for `/pathToConnection`?  Can you show the server-side socket.io code?

Comment: Why are you using `upgrade: false` and `reconnection: false` and `allowEI03: true`?   Do you have a specific reason for setting these?

Comment: edited the question, added code from node js

Comment: ***upgrade: false,*** ***reconnection: false,*** ***allowEI03: true,*** I added based on the solutions on the Internet, but they did not help at all, all I can leave is reconnection: false, so that when the connection is broken so that he tries to reconnect

Comment: By the way, I also want to clarify that I run this code on the namecheap hosting and it doesn’t work, maybe this is a hosting problem, but it’s unlikely that I contacted support with this question, they said that there were no problems on their side, they also asked them to opened port 3000 for me

Comment: Lots of inexpensive hosting does not directly support webSockets (which is the transport that socket.io uses).  They use proxies that are not configured for the long lived webSocket connections.  I don't know your specific hosting provider, but that is definitely something to investigate further.  If this works when you self host, but doesn't work on namecheap, then you probably have your answer.  You either need to make a configuration change or pay for a plan that includes webSocket support.

Comment: You should remove all these `upgrade: false, reconnection: false, allowEI03: true`.  They are not your main problem, but should not be used here.

Comment: The client is trying to connect over TLS (using `wss://`), but your server code is running a plain HTTP server. Unless your hosting provider provides a TLS termination proxy, you need to use `ws://` from the client.

Comment: I've found comments like this when searching for "namecheap websockets": *It is not possible with the Shared hosting plans Namecheap provides. You will need a VPS or a dedicated server with Namecheap to proceed.*

Comment: jfriend00, I wrote to those support, they told me that my socket io is supported

Comment: robertklep, I tried through ws or wss, nothing happens