# socket.io determine if a user is online or offline. Should I store the data in a database?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, real-time

I was going through this question: [socket.io determine if a user is online or offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134623/socket-io-determine-if-a-user-is-online-or-offline).

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32139326/9953550) I have seen that an object containing the online users is created. In a production app should you store this data in a database like redis? Or is it okay if it stays saved in memory in the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not store the users in the server's memory, imagine this case:

for some reason you need to restart the server, a crash, a new version update, a new release and the memory of the server gets reset and you loose the users object.

So for this redis looks like a great option to store users data.

Comment: @sebbas Tian can you please give some example in which form or structure we have to store online and offline user detail in redis.