# Show user status(online or offline) in my app

Tags: node.js

I have an education app that written by node.js and express.js
I want to show user status(online or offline) side profile photo
How can do it???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [socket.io determine if a user is online or offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134623/socket-io-determine-if-a-user-is-online-or-offline)

Answer (score 1):

Using `socket.io` is a good choice here: `https://socket.io`.

Once a user logs in successfully, you can `emit` an event to broadcast to everybody else that he is `online`. Similarly, when the user logs out, you can `emit` another event to broadcast to everybody else that he went `offline`. (Also when he closes the browser without logging out properly).

Using `socketio` you can `emit` and listen to events between the client and the server. You can broadcast events to multiple clients, you can add clients to `rooms` and broadcast events specifically to the clients in the room, and do a whole lot of things!

Good luck.